# Using a List of and undefined type as a parameter and return type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a method which takes in a list a file location as parameters and returns a list of that user-defined type. I have already created a method which returns the properties of a type, but I want to use the names of the properties to try and match them up to the keys in the `.json` file.

I have already got the code working, but only if the type is explicitly stated. I have a user-defined type called `Item`, which looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Item(int id, string name, double weight, int value)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This is fine, but at some point, I may want to use the same process for a list of another user-defined type, for example:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public float TopSpeed { get; set; }

    public Item(string registration, string model, float topSpeed, int value)
    {
        Registration = registration;
        Model = model;
        TopSpeed = topSpeed;
    }
}
```

Is this possible or am I missing something? Would I have to create a duplicate method, where the only thing that differs is the type of list? Here is part of my code, which I hope explains what I want to achieve:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using LitJson;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Program
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataParser dataParser = new DataParser();
            List<Item> database = new List<Item>();
            string location = "/Items.json";
            database = dataParser.ConstructItemDatabase(database, location);
        }
    }

    public class DataParser
    {
        public List<IndefiniteType> ConstructItemDatabase(List<IndefiniteType> list, string fileLocation)
        {
            //search property names of the list type and add create new objects within the list, based on the file.

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe [generic methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/twcad0zb.aspx) could help you there.

Comment: I think your best solution would be to encapsulate each DataParser into its own class, 1 for cars, 1 for item etc... expose an interface and then use DataParser Factory to return you a specific implementation.

Comment: Do you want to re-create a Newtonsoft Js serializer ?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to deserialize json. This is not a simple thing to do easily in the general case but fortunately other people have already done this so you don't need to. As Fabjan said Newtonsoft json library is I think the usual recommendation for doing this. This has generic methods were you can pass in and object and the json and it will populate all the properties as appropriate. I'd suggest going and looking it up and seeing if this doesn't just solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for Generics and Newtonsoft JS serializer:

```
public class DataParser
{
    // to deserialize database from file
    public T ConstructItemDatabase<T>(string fileLocation)
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }

    // to serialize (save) database to a file
    public void SaveItemDatabaseToJson<T>(string fileLocation, T database)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database);

        File.WriteAllText(fileLocation, json);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var parser = new DataParser();

parser.SaveItemDatabaseToJson("myDb.json", myListToSerialize);

var myDesirializedList = parser.ConstructItemDatabase<List<Car>>("myDb.json");
```

P.S.

Add `Newtonsoft.Json` library to your project by opening Nuget package manager and searching for it on nuget.org.

Comment: That works perfectly thanks. I was basically trying to create my own method that does exactly that, so this makes life easier.

Comment: Well, generally with developing in C# there are a lot of stuff (mostly nugget packages and system libraries) that can help to solve common problems. With Newtonsoft JS read about `JsonSerializerSettings` class, and try to use Indention when serializing your class - it'll make your resulting json readable from notepad etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand how you use `fileLocation` but you could use a generic method to achieve what you want:

```
public static List<T> ConstructItemDatabase<T>(List<T> list, string fileLocation) where T : new()
{
    // add new Item
    list.Add(new T());

    // if you need a list of all the properties:
    PropertyInfo [] allProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();


    return list;
}
```

`T` is a placeholder for the type that you want to have.

`where T : new()` restricts the types to only the ones that have a parameterless constructor. So you can be sure, that it is possible to create a new instance

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it didn't give me the result I needed and using Newtonsoft does exactly what I need.